stratifolds and manifolds: the passage between the two
In the introduction to the book by Kreck, I do not follow the paragraph given in the snippet
below. He says $n-$dimensional stratifold is a smooth manifold iff $\mathbf{S}^i = \emptyset$. But in his definition of stratifold there is no mention of charts which is essential to  $n-$dimensional smooth manifolds. I understand the weakening of $C^\infty$ to continuous $f:\mathbf{S}\to\mathbb{R}$, but I'm lacking the presence of charts to obtain $n-$dimensinal smooth manifolds in the definition of stratifold !
EDIT
The whole thing would be somewhat clearer if $f$ were difeomorphisms.


As I understand, here the author introduces stratifolds in "a completely informal way that does not replace the definition of stratifolds" in order to provide a feeling for them. So I think that to clarify your understanding of stratifolds your should proceed farther, to their definitions and basic properties and so forth.

Before talking about charts, I'm puzzled by what even $C^\infty$ means in this paragraph. To define a derivative $\frac{f(x')-f(x)}{|x'-x|}$ you need to divide by a norm, but in this general topological space, where would that norm come from? So as Alex says, this is more like an overview of the concept than a definition.

Nevertheless, assuming some set of smooth functions, we could form the set of germs of such functions around each point $p\in \mathbf S$, these would hopefully form a vector space (which we could losely call a "tangent" space), and that could be a starting point for building a chart around that point. That's still imprecise informal reasoning, though.
